# how to calculate determinant of matrix n times

Tags: python

Hi I have come across a problem and Im wondering if you could help me.

Im trying to get m values of DET (determinant of matrix) with shifting factor Cf .  I could just get one value of det and couldn't work out a code to get 1000 values with for loop.

Here is the input code:

```
n = 30
Cf = np.linspace(0-.1,n)
m = range(1000)

for i in Cf:
      C = np.random.randn(n,n). 
      C = [:, n-1] =C = [ :, n-2]
      Ci = np.eye(n)
      DET = np.linalg.det( C+(Ci*i))
```

Comment: your code seems to have syntax errors, can you make sure to post a working code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are generating a set of values. Thus you need a proper storage for them: `list` or `numpy.array` or `set` etc.
You may put

```
DET = []
```

before loop and

```
DET.append(np.linalg.det( C+(Ci*i)))
```

instead `DET =`

Comment: Hi thanks for your ans. This definitely helps . This problem has two loops:
1.  calculate the determinant with  different values of shifting factor (30 values) 2. repeat that 1000 times , your ans solved first loop. Im still not sure about second loop.

Comment: To repeat 1000 times you need to add another loop like `for _ range(1000): `
 above `for i in Cf:`